# Excel VBA copy hyperlink from a cell to a column in a table

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I would like to copy rows from a source sheet to a target table. Coping the values is no problem.

The column A in the source sheet contains a hyperlink to a website.
I would like to copy the hyperlink too.

However this code gives an error (type mismatch).

```
Sub Copy_Hyperlink()
    Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ActiveTable As ListObject
    Dim Row_Number As Integer
    Dim Last_Row As Integer
    Dim ActiveRow As ListRow
    Dim Hyperlink As Hyperlink
    Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ActiveTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")    

    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Last_Row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Row_Number = 2 To Last_Row
        Set ActiveRow = ActiveTable.ListRows.Add
        ActiveRow.Range(1, 1).Value = Range("A" & Row_Number).Value
        ActiveRow.Range(1, 2).Value = Range("B" & Row_Number).Value
        ActiveRow.Range(1, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Range _
    ("A" &   Row_Number).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
    Next Row_Number
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line is the error occuring?

Comment: Note: `Row_Number` and `Last_Row` should be of type `Long` not `Integer`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. I recommend to [always use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613)!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues but without explanation or responses we won't be able to give you a definitive answer.

I am not convinced that everything is working fine except for adding the hyperlink, but you can confirm that by **commenting out** the line that adds the hyperlink and running your code again.

```
' ActiveRow.Range(1, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Range("A" & Row_Number ).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
```

If the code works fine now, then there could still be a number of issues.

I assume you are probably trying to get a hyperlink from a cell that doesn't *have* a hyperlink (but I don't know since you didn't share your data.)  If so you can use `Hyperlinks.Count` to check if there is a usable link.

You are definitely using `Hyperlink.Add` incorrectly.

**Read more** here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and then edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Also, please check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanx, the soultion was to add an Anchor: 'ActiveRow.Range(1, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveRow.Range(1, 1), Address:=Range("A" & Row_Number).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address'